# Will included references somehow can change how the compiled program works?

Tags: c#, reference, nuget, nuget-package

I wonder because when I, for example do `install-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi.helppages` it will install the help pages + about 6 dependencies like razor etc.. Then when I try to uninstall it it will only uninstall the package itself and none of the dependencies.

Now I know that this is a bit on the *ocd* side, but it's like I am and I wonder if I keep those referenced in my project will it somehow worsen/make slower my application?

I'm using empty WebApi as an example here.

Answer (score 0):

The references are loaded when they are needed (there are dll's), so it will make slower your application as soon as you use it, if none are used, none are loaded.